# How to connect the shield of a cable only on one side, if I need to transfer GND from one end to the other?

Tags: audio, shielding

I have one jack output: Left, Right, GND. I am using a shielded cable to transfer this signal to an amp. I've read about ground loop and that I should only wire the shield of the cable on one of the two ends.

How can I do this as long as I need to send the GND from one end to the other?

Cable (v1): two wires (left, right) + shield (GND) connected both side

Cable (v2): three wires (left, right, GND connected from one side to the other) + shield (GND) connected one side only.

From my point of view, the two variants are similar. So then how to connect the shield.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is, you can't.

You need to connect the ground, regardless of it being the shield or not in a standard audio cable.

Since you need to connect ground, it can create a ground loop, but only if there are other ground connections.

And even if it forms a ground loop, then another thing is if it will ever be a problem or not.

So, normally, people will buy a standard audio cable with suitable connectors and connect it between the two devices without thinking it further.

If you do encounter problems, then it is not only about how to make the connections between the two devices you intend to connect, it is the whole system of all the connections all the devices have to all other systems, like how they are powered or connected to mains etc.

Comment: One solution is to put 1:1 isolation transformers between the source and destination. It sounds like audio signals so a suitable stereo (dual) transformer so be easy to find.

Comment: @DoxyLover Based on previous questions, OP is connecting a MP3 player module to home stereo, so that or any other normal home audio setup generally does not require isolation transformers.